# How to find the appropriate fit?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

Imagine we are given this set of data:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
```

We fit the data with:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x],
```

and we can obtain $a$ and $b$.

Now, if we are given that the $y$ coordinates in the data list have the variance of, for example, $0.5$, $0.3$, $1.3$, $0.2$, $0.9$, and $0.7$, can we use this additional information to improve fitting?

Comment: You'd use the option `Weights -> 1/{0.5, 0.3, ...}` in NonlinearModelFit.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks! What does it mean?

Comment: It basically means that points with a greater uncertainty have a smaller influence on the fit than the ones with a small uncertainty.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Do you know a good source about these stuff to read?

Comment: Honestly? I had to puzzle most of this together myself from a number of sources and general common-sense maths. I find that the world of statistics and fitting is fraught with bad advice and poorly explained concepts, unfortunately. The essential point is that when you do least-square fitting (like `NonlinearModelFit` does), then you're essentially assuming that the errors are normally distributed and that you can estimate the fit parameters with maximum loglikelihood estimation. Applying weights to your least-square fit is then equivalent to changing the variances of the errors.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks for your comment.